# ServiceStack API Explorer: Login form not working when deployed to IIS as a "sub-application"

Tags: servicestack

I have a aspnet core (dotnet 6) application that uses ServiceStack authentication.

The built-in login form is displayed when the browser tries to access protected services, as expected.

One can login successfully, when the app is installed as a stand-alone site in IIS.

However, when the same app is installed as an "application" inside an existing IIS site, that same login form doesn't work.

In the browser's "developer tools/console" one can see the following javascript error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Authenticate is not defined
    at Proxy.login (ui:866:10)
    at login (ui:862:137)
    at Proxy.onsubmit (ui:1025:1)
    at eval (eval at We (petite-vue.js?vfx=6,2:1:8737), <anonymous>:3:26)
    at HTMLFormElement.i (petite-vue.js?vfx=6,2:1:8122)
login @ ui:866
login @ ui:862
onsubmit @ ui:1025
eval @ VM102:3
i @ petite-vue.js?vfx=6,2:1
```

The exact line of the error is:

```
let auth=new Authenticate()
```

The web.config is for this sub-aplication:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\MyApp.exe" arguments=".\MyApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

What can be done to troubleshoot this error?

Comment: Can you try upgrading to the latest [v6.3.1+ on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget)

Comment: @mythz version 6.3.1 solved the problem. Thank you.